# Linker command failed with exit code 1 with only this error

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

The linker failed. This is the only error I get. And it does not expand (`-v`).

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/mac/Desktop/rx/x/cordova-ios/platforms/ios/MxSDK/libMxiSnap.a,
missing required architecture x86_64 in file
/Users/mac/Desktop/rx/x/cordova-ios/platforms/ios/MxSDK/libMiSnap.a (2 slices)

ld: file is universal (4 slices) but does not contain a(n)x86_64 
slice: /Users/mac/Desktop/rx/x/cordova-ios/platforms/ios/MxSDK/OptionalLibraries/MiSnapBarcodeScanner/libBarcodeScanner.a 
file'/Users/mac/Desktop/rx/x/cordova-ios/platforms/ios/MxSDK/OptionalLibraries/MiSnapBarcodeScanner/libBarcodeScanner.a for architecture x86_64 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: This could be caused by one entity compiled for 32-bit platform and another compiled for 64-bit platform.  Verify that all entities are compiled for the same platformtype.

Comment: The file here is .a file. And cannot be modified.